# Should we create custom pages for all objects?

Tags: salesforce

I noticed that salesforce doesn't allow to override control function for all objects.
Say if you want to do something whenever objects get saved there is no way to attach the action
unless you create a custom page and include either standard controller or extension. Or if you want
to add the same meta-tag on all pages I run into this limitation. Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally - no. Roughly speaking if Salesforce doesn't allow you to do something it usually means there's pretty good hint you're doing in it wrong. I realize it sounds like I'm a fanboy but in reality - can you expand your question with concrete example why would you want to do something like that? For example governor limits are evil, annoying etc. - but they force you to write effective code that doesn't strain the database too much.

> if you want to do something whenever objects get saved

That's what triggers are for. Ask yourself a question if the "action" you need to make should happen only from web UI or also when performed from API (mass data load, a smartphone application etc).

> if you want to add the same meta-tag on all pages

You could maybe pull off similar result by adding a component to the sidebar. It won't cover all cases (like accessing Reports/Dashboards) but it's hard to say more without knowing what you're really after. Then again - custom VF page overrides won't help you when it comes to Reports either.

Comment: Here is an example. Say if you want to install this plugin so that user will be prompted if trying to navigate away from the page while creating/updating object. I guess only way is to create custom apex pages where you update/create objects.                    http://www.papercut.com/products/free_software/are-you-sure/demo/are-you-sure-demo.html

Comment: Prior to current (Spring'13) you were able to inject Javascript for such stuff in the edit page layout in the section headers (it was a hack, not intended behavior). As sameer writes - you can still put it into sidebar. Personally I find such popups annoying (breaking the UI) but if it's what your business wants... You can get this behaviour out of the box by using "Service Cloud Console" by the way. It's within standard SF but needs separate licence (checkbox on user record), speeds up work of advanced SF users.

Comment: P.S. As always - you're welcome to vote on an idea ;) https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrYyAAK

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add this as a comment, but was unable to.

Anyways, For the example that you mentioned in the comment, You can add that jQuery plugin in the Home page side bar component and activate the plugin only on those custom objects where you wnat to run this plugin. You might already know that we can deduce which object a record belongs to by looking at the 1st 3 letter of the record Id, using this logic, check if the record belongs to the custom object you want your plugin to act on and run the plugin.

But As eyescream has pointed out adding script in side bar has its own limitations: you cannot use the global variables , side bar components are not loaded on the reports and dashboard tabs etc.

-ಸಮಿರ್